# Sony Smartwatch - Detecting extra tap?

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, sony-smartwatch

I am looking for a general pattern for SmartWatch development. I am having an issue with my apps. If the user taps on the screen sometimes it make take a second for the screen to update with a new image. If the user gets impatient they will tap again. This causes them to press on something that they don't want.

Is there a way to detect that the user is viewing the latest screen update (a callback)? Or any general idea on how to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to implement a callback on a screen update.  However, one possibility may be to check the timestamp of the touch events and if the events happen too quickly (say within a 1 second window) then ignore the second event.

Comment: I thought about this idea but this is the kind of solution that I want to avoid. The response time of the watch seems to be based on the quality of the Bluetooth connection. So it would be difficult to pick a good amount of time to ignore touches.

Comment: The answer by Marlin is the correct way. I would put 2 seconds time frame, just ignore the event that is the same as the one less than 2 secs ago.